# Can I incorporate a \unicode-based formula into TeXShop 3.64?

Tags: unicode, input-encodings, wolfram-mathematica

The Mathematica TeXForm command gives me

```
\text{DifferenceRoot}[\{\unicode{f818},\unicode{f80d}\}\unicode{f4a1}\{(-15
   \unicode{f80d}-42) \unicode{f818}(\unicode{f80d})-15
   \unicode{f818}(\unicode{f80d}+1)+(15 \unicode{f80d}-3)
   \unicode{f818}(\unicode{f80d}+2)-180
   \unicode{f80d}-38=0,\unicode{f818}(1)=0,\unicode{f818}(2)=6\}][\alpha ]
```

But TeXShop reports "783: Undefined control sequence".

Is there a way for me to address this problem?

Comment: The codes are in the Private Use Area, so they're font specific and have no predefined meaning.

Comment: Thanks egreg, but can I get TeXShop to yield a PDF document? Do I have to specify a font? What is the Private Use Area?

Comment: Unless you know precisely what font is Mathematica using *and* you have it, it's impossible to say what the codes refer to. The Private Use Area is a range of Unicode code points that font developer can use for their font, but have no predefined meaning; so in order to get something out of that code the correspondence between (hex) number and symbol must be known.

Comment: For instance, at U+F818 Aboriginal Serif has a “T with tilde”, whereas Ubuntu has a “subscript digit 4”.

Comment: Thanks very much egreg! Wow, quite technical. So--as a practical matter--is there any way I can proceed to get the desired expression into my PDF document? Maybe I should contact Mathematica/Wolfram, and/or post my question on the MathematicaStackExchange website?

Comment: Possibly Mathematica.SE is a good place where asking

Comment: Mathematica's TeX generator is pretty outdated and this `\unicode` stuff is basically what it does when it cannot handle some characters.  It's not standard TeX/LaTeX and it's not easy to handle it automatically.  You could write to Wolfram support and ask them how this output is actually supposed to be used in LaTeX.  The more people complain about TeXForm, the more likely that they'll finally update it.